# python :same character, different behavior

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode, encode

I'm generating file names from a list pulled out from a postgres DB with Python 2.7.9. In this list there are words with special char. Normally I use `''.join()` to record the name and fire it to my loader but I have just one name that want be recognized. the .py is set for utf-8 coding, but the words are in Portuguese, I think latin-1 coding.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
templist = ['+ Orégano','- Búfala','+ Rúcola']
count_ins = (len(templist)-1)
while (count_ins >= 0 ):
    kot_istructions = AudioSegment.from_ogg('/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/'+"".join(templist[count_ins])+'.ogg')
    count_ins-=1
    play(kot_istructions)
```

The first two files are loaded:

`/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/+ Orégano.ogg`

`/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/- Búfala.ogg`

The third should be:

`/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/+ Rúcola.ogg`

But python is trying to load

`/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/+ R\xc3\xbacola.ogg`

Why just this one? I've tried to use `normalize()` to remove the accent but since this is a string the method didn't work. 
Print works well, as db update. Just file name creation doesn't works as expected.
Suggestions?

Comment: Unicode strings require the "u" prefix in Python 2: `[u'+ Orégano', u'- Búfala', u'+ Rúcola']`.

Comment: Please do use iteration instead of manually counting indices. A simple `for word in templist` suffices. Then, get rid of the join-call, it's only working incidentially here because you only have one argument that is a string - it's not really doing what you think it is. The string representation looks like proper utf-8 encoding, the question is: is your filesystem's encoding utf-8?

Comment: Have you considered using python 3? The Unicode handling was redone.

Comment: @dlask : I can't edit the list because is generated in real time and used in various parts of the program.
@deets : Sometimes I need to edit "on the fly" an index count, is more quick to edit than `for/in` cycle. My filesystem (as my db) is set to `LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8` .
@A.L.Flanagan: I can't. I'm using python with Odoo and I need Python 2.7.

Comment: don't put an answer (sentence after "Solved") into the question. [Post it as your own answer instead](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the root cause might be that the encoding of these names in inconsisitent within your database.

If you run:

```
>>> 'R\xc3\xbacola'.decode('utf-8')
```

You get

```
u'R\xfacola'
```

which is in fact a Python `unicode`, correctly representing the name. So, what should you do? Although it's a really unclean programming style, you could play `.encode()/.decode()` whackamole, where you `try` to decode the raw string from your db using `utf-8`, and failing that, `latin-1`. It would look something like this:

```
try:
    clean_unicode = dirty_string.decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    clean_unicode = dirty_string.decode('latin-1')
```

As a general rule, always work with clean unicode objects within your own source, and only convert to an encoding on saving it out. Also, don't let people insert data into a database without specifying the encoding, as that will stop you from having this problem in the first place.

Hope that helps!

Comment: With `.encode()/.decode()` I get the same error, but with a different encoding: 
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/+ R\xfacola.ogg'`
Meaning your conversion is working indeed but is not the result I need.
Again, why just with `ú` in this position and not in the other case?

Comment: If you're looking for a file that already exists, what is the actual encoding in its name? Can you browse to it and see what it's name is?

Try running

   os.listdir('/home/effe/voice_orders/Voz/') and see how it's represented in your system.

Comment: `os.listdir` didn't report anything out of place. Anyway **THIS WAS** a problem with the file. Deleting the file and creating a new one solve the problem. Please don't ask me why. Thank you to point it out, +1 on your reply because even if was not the case your method enlightened me on how encode/decode works.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** Was a problem with the file. Deleting and build it again do the job.